# using subquery in between operator

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

hie all,

my query is this

```
select * from [order] where createdon<getdate()-7
and orderid between 
(select top 1 orderid from [order] where createdon<getdate()-7 order by orderid) as oId
and oId+100 order by orderid
```

It is giving error. please tell me where is it going wrong

my intention is to get 100 orders from order table which are older than 7 days. and please **dont suggest fetching it using row_number**

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't alias expressions in the `WHERE` clause. But since your subquery returns just one row, you could cross join it to the `[order]` table and filter on the returned top `orderid` value like this:

```
SELECT [order].*
FROM [order]
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT TOP 1 orderid
  FROM [order]
  WHERE createdon < GETDATE() - 7
  ORDER BY orderid
) toporder
WHERE [order].createdon < GETDATE() - 7
  AND [order].orderid BETWEEN toporder.orderid AND toporder.orderid + 100
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from 
(
    select top 100 * from [order] where 
    createdon<dateadd(day, -7, getdate())
    order by orderid desc
) 
order by orderid asc
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume you use MSSQL, use TOP keyword to limit output :

```
SELECT TOP 100 ...
```